# Howto get orderId from request object in node express

Tags: node.js, express

Its an xml request which is coming in node express, when I print `console.log( req.body)` then output is

```
{ 'ns:event':
{ '$': { 'xmlns:ns': 'NetoAPI' },
 currenttime: [ '2019-12-16 06:20:27' ],
 eventid: [ '1362' ],
 eventtype: [ 'Order' ],
 order: [ [Object] ] } }
```

And printing `console.log( JSON.stringify(req.body))` comes as

```
{"ns:event":{"$":{"xmlns:ns":"NetoAPI"},"currenttime":["2019-12-16 06:20:27"],"eventid":["1362"],"eventtype":["Order"],"order":[{"orderid":["JSHDSDS34"],"orderstatus":["Cancelled"]}]}}
```

I just want **orderid** from this object. While trying to access with `req.body.'ns:event'.order` then its an error.
**How can I get orderid from this ?**

Comment: Have you used bodyParser?

Comment: Yes, app.use(bodyParser.json({
 limit : config.bodyLimit
}));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
req.body['ns:event'].order[0].orderid[0]        //"JSHDSDS34"
req.body['ns:event'].order[0].orderstatus[0]    //"Cancelled"
```